# How can I use SQLite 3 with RubyOnRails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

First, I'm bad at english, so I can't give a lot of details.. I've been trying to create a website using ruby on rails:

```
rails new azer
rails generate controller pages home
```

The last command doesn't work and there's an error occuring during generating:

> /home/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177: in
>   'rescue in spec': Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the
>   gem is not loaded. Add gem 'sqlite3' to your Gemfile (and ensure its
>   version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).(Gem::LoadError)

So I opened my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.10'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
...
...
```

I'm unsure what might be the error cause thus I don't know how to proceed.

Versions:

```
Ruby     2.4.4
Rails    4.2.10
SQLite3  1.4.1.
```

EDIT : Thanks for your help everyone, I appreciate it ! I just tried to reinstall rails and it worked

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` after `rails new azer`?

Comment: Papy, the sentences like "I'm bad at english" are purposively edited out of the question. They don't help readers in any way and if editor find issue with the question, he will help and edit it for you.

Comment: @CAmador yes, and it sadly doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @Tatranskymedved Oh, sorry then. I just didn't want to get blamed for the lack of details

Comment: Is gem `sqlite3` actually installed? Run `gem list sqlite` to confirm. Is SQLite3 installed in your system?

Comment: @CAmador Yes, sqlite3 (1.4.1)

Comment: Did you run: `bundle exec rails db:create`(Rails 5) or `bundle exec rake db:create`(Rails 4) ? If no, are you able to run this? Are you seeing errors o new messages?

Comment: Another question: If you are starting a new rails' project, why are you don't using the last stable version? `rails 5.2.3` and `ruby 2.6.x`

Comment: Do you have already sqlite3 installed? Run `sqlite3 --version` from your terminal and tell us what is it returning please.

Comment: @hernanvicente Thanks for your help ! And I'm not using the last version because my company's still working on an old one. I suggested using the latest versions but they don't want to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems version 1.4.x won't work with Rails 4. Install version 1.3.13 instead:

Unisntall version 1.4.1:

```sh
gem uninstall sqlite3 -v1.4.1
```

Modify Gemfile:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.13'
```

And run `bundle install`.

Comment: Great, nice catch!